# Conda Environment Won't Activate

Tags: visual-studio, anaconda3

I am new to virtual environments, but I need to create one to use Python 3.9. I seem to have followed all the steps in downloading and using anaconda/vscode to create a conda environment. However, typing in "conda activate ENV_NAME" does not work. I'm currently working in Windows, and for certain reasons, cannot change to Linux if that would solve my problem.

I have tried the command multiple times, I have recreated the conda environment multiple times, and nothing seems to do the trick. Whenever I try to activate, nothing seems to happen; I don't get an error, and when I check, it still shows me being in th ebase environment.

Update: This has not been working in powershell within vscode. However, the command "conda activate ENV_NAME" does work within a normal powershell terminal window.

Update: I solved the problem. I need to open vscode from inside the conda environment, rather than the other way around.